# Permisos denegados para laravel

Tags: laravel, xampp, macos, permisos

Hola estoy creando un proyecto de laravel y siempre que lo abro me sale esto,  intenten darle permisos a la carpeta y no me funciona, la verdad no se que hacer y no lo he tocado solo use esto en la tarminal `composer create-project laravel/laravel demowebsite`
y de ahí fui a probarlo y salio esto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le di permisos a la carpeta y aun asi nada.

Estoy usando un MacBook no se si eso interfiera y me baje el ultimo Xampp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Pero es que no basta con darle permisos sólo al folder, tienes que darle permisos a todo su contenido de manera recursiva.

Ejecuta el siguiente comando en la terminal:

```
chmod -R 755 /ruta/al/folder
```

La `-R` significa que será de manera recursiva, y para un proyecto de laravel basta con los permisos `755`

Comment: Hice esto :
`MacBook-Air-de-Andres:extra andr3yvlz$ cd /Users/andr3yvlz/.bitnami/stackman/machines/xampp/volumes/root/htdocs/Tutorial` 
`MacBook-Air-de-Andres:Tutorial andr3yvlz$ chmod -R 755 Andr3yvlz/` y salio el mismo error

Comment: ¿Pero por qué tu carpeta en el error se llama `demowebsite` y acá tu pones una ruta diferente?

Comment: la que mostre era de ejemplo pero en la `Adr....`es donde alojare el proyecto y dado que ambas tienen exactamente lo mismo decidi hacer la prueba sobre la que va a ser donde hare el proyecto.

Comment: Si es así, ¿podrías checar los permisos que tiene ese archivo que te marca el error?, si tiene `755` significa que si lo hiciste correctamente y hay algo más.

Comment: El error sigue y use ese comando tal cual como ves en mi comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Con esto me funciona a mi

Para Linux:

```
sudo chgrp -R www-data storage bootstrap/cache;  sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache;  sudo chmod -R 777 storage/
```

Para Mac:

```
sudo chgrp -R _www storage bootstrap/cache;  sudo chmod -R ug+rwx storage bootstrap/cache;  sudo chmod -R 775 storage/
```